# Django REST Serializer not getting data from request

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have the following serializer setup to take in a postcode and return a list of service objects:

```
class ServiceSearchSerializer(Serializer):
area = CharField(max_length=16)
services = DictField(child=JSONField(), read_only=True)

def validate_area(self, value):
    if re.match('^[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9][A-Z0-9]? ?([0-9][A-Z]{2})?$', value) is None:
        raise ValidationError("This is not a valid postcode.")
```

And I tried to use this to create an API endpoint which out take in the area.

```
class ServiceSearchAPI(GenericAPIView):
serializer_class = ServiceSearchSerializer

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
        area = serializer.data['area']
        return Response(area)
```

However, when trying to get the area from the serializer, it returns None. But the value for request.data['area'] is correct. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just checked the [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#field-level-validation) and they specify returning the value. Try returning it like this:

```python
def validate_area(self, value):
    if re.match('^[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9][A-Z0-9]? ?([0-9][A-Z]{2})?$', value) is None:
        raise ValidationError("This is not a valid postcode.")
    return value
```